# animation (or not) to fill a bottle image

Tags: flutter, dart

I would like to create an animation that fills a bottle based on state value.
If it's too complicated with an animation, it's ok to just fill the bottle with a linear color.

This is the image of the bottle.

[image]

I am trying with ShaderMask:

```
ShaderMask(
    shaderCallback: (rect) {
        return LinearGradient(
            begin: Alignment.topCenter,
            end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            colors: [Colors.white, Colors.red]).createShader(rect);
        },
    blendMode: BlendMode.darken,
    child: Image.asset(
         'image.png',
         height: 250,
    ),
)
```

But the mask is applied to all image. I would need to not fill the bottle completely, but based on state value.